# Chart JS 2.x don't show multiple data in tooltip with callback from MySql Database

Tags: mysql, chart.js

I need to show an additional info ("active" field in table from MySql Database) and put in the tooltip with callbacks function.

screenshot linechart

[image]

code

```
tooltips : {
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)',
          enabled: true,
          intersect: false,
            callbacks: {
                label: function (tooltipItems, data) {
                       return data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].label +': ' + tooltipItems.yLabel + '%';
                       },
                afterLabel: function (tooltipItems, data) {
                            return 'Stati Attivi: ' + tooltipItems.--name of field?--;  // return a string that you wish to append
                       }
            }
        }
```

----------------UPDATE------------------------

I change somenthing but connected to 1 data.
I need every faction have his personal data in the tooltip.

[image]

this is the entire code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  /**
   * call the data.php file to fetch the result from db table.
   */
  $.ajax({
    url : "/ins-bgs/lakota/line-charts/data.php",
    type : "GET",
    success : function(data){
      console.log(data);

      //for influence factions
      var influence = {
        ac1 : [],
        lc2 : [],
        hbblc3 : [],
        li4 : [],
        bollp5 : [],
        lec6 : [],
        lpe7 : [],
        pol8: []
      };
      
      //for active states
      var active = {
        ac1 : [],
        lc2 : [],
        hbblc3 : [],
        li4 : [],
        bollp5 : [],
        lec6 : [],
        lpe7 : [],
        pol8: []
      };
      
      //for date and time
      var created_at = {
        ac1 : []
      };

      var len = data.length;

      //for influence factions
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (data[i].id_fact == "ac1") {
          influence.ac1.push(data[i].influence);
        }
        else if (data[i].id_fact == "lc2") {
          influence.lc2.push(data[i].influence);
        }
        else if (data[i].id_fact == "hbblc3") {
          influence.hbblc3.push(data[i].influence);
        }
        else if (data[i].id_fact == "li4") {
          influence.li4.push(data[i].influence);
        }
        else if (data[i].id_fact == "bollp5") {
          influence.bollp5.push(data[i].influence);
        }
        else if (data[i].id_fact == "lec6") {
          influence.lec6.push(data[i].influence);
        }
        else if (data[i].id_fact == "lpe7") {
          influence.lpe7.push(data[i].influence);
        }
        else if (data[i].id_fact == "pol8") {
          influence.pol8.push(data[i].influence);
        }
      }

      //for active states
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (data[i].id_fact == "ac1") {
        active.ac1.push(data[i].active);
        }
      }
      
      //for date and time
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (data[i].id_fact == "ac1") {
        created_at.ac1.push(data[i].created_at);
        }
      }

      //get canvas
      var ctx = $("#line-chartcanvas");

      var data = {
        labels : created_at.ac1,
        datasets : [
          {
            label : "Argus Corporation",
            data : influence.ac1,
            backgroundColor : 'rgba(210, 145, 42, 0.4)',
            borderColor : 'rgba(210, 145, 42, 1.0)',
            pointBorderColor: 'rgba(210, 145, 42, 1.0)',
            pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(210, 145, 42, 1.0)',
            fill : false,
            lineTension : 0,
            pointRadius : 4,
            pointHoverRadius: 5
          },
          {
            label : "Lakota Corp.",
            data : influence.lc2,
            backgroundColor : 'rgba(152,56,67,0.4)',
            borderColor : 'rgba(152,56,67,1.0)',
            pointBorderColor: 'rgba(152,56,67,1.0)',
            pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(152,56,67,1.0)',
            fill : false,
            lineTension : 0,
            pointRadius : 4,
            pointHoverRadius: 5
          },
          {
            label : "HN Bootis Blue Life Co",
            data : influence.hbblc3,
            backgroundColor : 'rgba(175,67,73,0.4)',
            borderColor : 'rgba(175,67,73,1.0)',
            pointBorderColor: 'rgba(175,67,73,1.0)',
            pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(175,67,73,1.0)',
            fill : false,
            lineTension : 0,
            pointRadius : 4,
            pointHoverRadius: 5
          },
          {
            label : "Lakota Independents",
            data : influence.li4,
            backgroundColor : 'rgba(201,126,39,0.4)',
            borderColor : 'rgba(201,126,39,1.0)',
            pointBorderColor: 'rgba(201,126,39,1.0)',
            pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(201,126,39,1.0)',
            fill : false,
            lineTension : 0,
            pointRadius : 4,
            pointHoverRadius: 5
          },
          {
            label : "Bureau of Lakota Law Party",
            data : influence.bollp5,
            backgroundColor : 'rgba(67,55,201,0.4)',
            borderColor : 'rgba(67,55,201,1.0)',
            pointBorderColor: 'rgba(67,55,201,1.0)',
            pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(67,55,201,1.0)',
            fill : false,
            lineTension : 0,
            pointRadius : 4,
            pointHoverRadius: 5
          },
          {
            label : "LP 440-38 Electronics Company",
            data : influence.lec6,
            backgroundColor : 'rgba(37,176,32,0.4)',
            borderColor : 'rgba(37,176,32,1.0)',
            pointBorderColor: 'rgba(37,176,32,1.0)',
            pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(37,176,32,1.0)',
            fill : false,
            lineTension : 0,
            pointRadius : 4,
            pointHoverRadius: 5
          },
          {
            label : "Lakota Power Exchange",
            data : influence.lpe7,
            backgroundColor : 'rgba(250,110,10,0.4)',
            borderColor : 'rgba(250,110,10,1.0)',
            pointBorderColor: 'rgba(250,110,10,1.0)',
            pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(250,110,10,1.0)',
            fill : false,
            lineTension : 0,
            pointRadius : 4,
            pointHoverRadius: 5
          },
          {
            label : "Posse of Lakota",
            data : influence.pol8,
            backgroundColor : 'rgba(141,198,67,0.4)',
            borderColor : 'rgba(141,198,67,1.0)',
            pointBorderColor: 'rgba(141,198,67,1.0)',
            pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(141,198,67,1.0)',
            fill : false,
            lineTension : 0,
            pointRadius : 4,
            pointHoverRadius: 5
          }
        ]
      };

      var options = {
        title : {
          display : true,
          position : "top",
          text : 'Sistema Lakota / Influenze delle fazioni',
          fontSize : 18,
          fontColor : "#111"
        },
        legend : {
          display : true,
          position : "bottom"
        },
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                display: true,
                color: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
                lineWidth: 2,
                borderDash: [5]
            }
        }],
        xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                display: true,
                color: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
                lineWidth: 1
            }
        }]
      },
        tooltips : {
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)',
          enabled: true,
          intersect: false,
            callbacks: {
                label: function (tooltipItems, data) {
                       return data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].label +': ' + tooltipItems.yLabel + '%';
                       },
                afterLabel: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                           var actsta = 'Stati Attivi: ' + active.ac1;
                           return actsta;
                       }
            }
        }
      };

      var chart = new Chart( ctx, {
        type : "line",
        data : data,
        options : options
      } );

    },
    error : function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });

});
```